# Sort 2D numpy array (by row) based on another 2D array of same shape

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy

With two arrays:

```
X = np.array([[1,2,3], [2,3,1]])
X
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 1]])
Y = np.array([['A','B', 'C'], ['A','B', 'C']])
Y
array([['A', 'B', 'C'],
       ['A', 'B', 'C']], 
     dtype='|S1')
```

I am trying to sort Y based on the values of X row by row without looping through each row, i.e

```
xord = X.argsort()

for i in range(X.shape[0]):
    print Y[i][xord[i]]

['A' 'B' 'C']
['C' 'A' 'B']
```

Is there a more efficient way to sort array Y based on the corresponding row order of X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Altering Mazdak's answer based on AdrianBoeh's comment, after I found this similar question here [How to using numpy.argsort on a 2D array to sort another 2D array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66178558/how-to-using-numpy-argsort-on-a-2d-array-to-sort-another-2d-array) :

```
    X = np.array([[1,2,3], [2,3,1]])
    Y = np.array([['A','B', 'C'],['X','Y','Z']])
    s=np.argsort(X)
    np.take_along_axis(Y,s,axis=1)
```

It seems that the `np.take(Y,s)` applies the indexes `s` only to the first row of `Y`, so `np.take_along_axis` is necessary in this kind of problem if the rows of `Y` are not all the same.

Answer (score 1):

First you can use `np.argsort` to get the indices of `X` elements based on those position after sorting,then you can get the elements from `Y` based on the indices of `X` with `np.take()`:

```
>>> s=np.argsort(X)
>>> np.take(Y,s)
array([['A', 'B', 'C'],
       ['C', 'A', 'B']], 
      dtype='|S1')
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. How does this maintain alignment of rows like the for loop would have? Try using Y as below, it shows the issue more clearly
Y = np.array([['A','B', 'C'], ['X','Y', 'Z']])